Symfony Dependency Injection: How to dynamically inject the correct implementation of an interface based on context?
I'm using the symfony/dependency-injection:^5.4 component in my project, and I have a scenario where I need to inject different implementations of an interface based on the context.
Here’s my setup:

I have two services, PasswordSetter100 and PasswordSetter200, both implementing PasswordSetterInterface.
These services follow an internal naming convention, and the correct implementation is chosen dynamically depending on the context.
I use a factory, ByTenantFactory, that depends on the container and decides which implementation to use based on certain variables.

In my UserController, I want to inject PasswordSetterInterface and have Symfony automatically provide the correct implementation depending on the context.
Here’s the service configuration I thought would work:
services:
  PasswordSetterInterface:
    factory: ['@ByTenantFactory', 'create']
 
  ByTenantFactory:
    class: App\Factory\ByTenantFactory
    arguments:
      - '@service_container'

  # All controllers are autowired services

However, when I try this setup, Symfony’s container complains that I need to choose which implementation to inject for PasswordSetterInterface.
Is there a way to make this work without explicitly specifying which implementation to use in the services configuration?
